# Moq'ing Reference Variables

Tags: vb.net, unit-testing, mocking, moq

We are starting to see the benefits of Test Driven Development and decided to take the first steps in allowing TDD to drive our design. (AKA just testing) Then hopefully once we see the benefits of testing and how poor mocking does at allowing us to design well, we will move away from them and re-factor.. yada yada, anyway

I have found a few topics that have been similar but nothing I can really build on. I have something like below:

```
<Test()>
  Public Sub TestMockWithReferenceVariable()
   Dim expected As New Dictionary(Of String, Object)
   expected.Add("test", 1)
   Dim pass As New Dictionary(Of String, Object)


   Dim mock = New Moq.Mock(Of ITestDM)()
   mock.Setup(Function(m) m.Load(Of String)("test", pass)).Returns("Test")

   Dim sing As New DMSinglton(mock.Object)
   Dim result As String = sing.Load(Of String)("test", pass)

   Assert.AreEqual("Test", result)
   Assert.AreEqual(expected, pass)
  End Sub



 Public Interface ITestDM
  Function Load(Of T)(ByVal sp As String, ByVal params As Dictionary(Of String, Object)) As T
 End Interface
```

Is there a way to let me use Moq to change the passed in dictionary to a different one, allowing these tests to pass?

Comment: I don't understand your example, because it's not clear what the 'DMSinglton' class does and what the test exactly wants to assert in the end. Please edit. Btw.: If 'DMSinglton' really is meant to be a singleton (according to the design pattern), there must not be a call to 'new'.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this outside MOQ by using collection suppoprt from your unit testing framework. I can think of at least two ways to achieve this using MsTest or by using `SequenseEquals` Linq method.

```
Dictionary<string, string> dict = new Dictionary<string, string> { { "test", "test" } };
Dictionary<string, string> dict2 = new Dictionary<string, string> { { "test", "test" } };
//MsTest CollectionAssert tests if two collections contain the same elements
CollectionAssert.AreEquivalent(dict, dict2);
//Another way to do the same thing - using SequenceEquals
Assert.IsTrue(dict.SequenceEqual(dict2));
```

Assuming the reference types used in the dictionary override `Equals` method, this will work(Value types will just work out of the box).